# maven build issue and getting error Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=2

Tags: maven

when i'm trying to build my project i'm getting below error message 
"Unable to execute Cobertura. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
"
command I used to build my project - mvn clean install

Note: I have already set my JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME and /bin/sh is already present in my system.

OS: Mac - 10.13.6

Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30) Maven home: /Users/Documents/software/apache-maven-3.3.3 Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: /Applications/Developers/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/OracleJDK8/Contents/Home/jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: US-ASCII OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Could someone help me why it is happening and solution.

Comment: Can you run `mvn clean install  -v` and paste the output in question itself ?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/Documents/software/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Applications/Developers/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/OracleJDK8/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: US-ASCII
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `mvn clean install -X`

Comment: Unable to execute Cobertura. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument (default) on project pp: Unable to execute Cobertura.Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=2, No such file or directory. Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: I suspect problem is causing by running the JVM on some kind of sandbox environment. I think, Cobertura plugin is trying to run shell script but unable to do so due to some restriction. 

Can you try by removing `cobertura-maven-plugin` from your pom.xml ?

Comment: yes I did that and it worked but when I tried to build in different system its getting build (without removing the cobertura dependency in pom)